# jQuery css() ends with

Tags: jquery

EDIT: I apologize, I expected `css` to work like eg. `height` and to return a whole style when called without parameters. It doesn't work like that. Just call `.css('css property name')`.

---

Run this simple fiddle - any use of `.css()` (eg. `$('body').css()`) on any jQuery objects ends with error, in all my browsers (os x chrome, safari, ff) and with multiple jQuery versions (latest, 3.1, 2.x).

I have no idea what's wrong - css() should just work everywhere. Any idea?

https://jsfiddle.net/hueys5ok/

```
jquery.js:3988 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at camelCase (VM292 jquery.js:3988)
at Function.css (VM292 jquery.js:6518)
at jQuery.fn.init.<anonymous> (VM292 jquery.js:6676)
at access (VM292 jquery.js:3968)
at jQuery.fn.init.css (VM292 jquery.js:6658)
at window.onload ((index):72)
```

Comment: It will only work when you pass the css property name you are trying to retrieve. Not passing a property won't just get all of it -  see [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: have you ever actually used `.css()` in that manner before?, I mean, not `.css('display')` or `.css('display', 'block')`, but `.css()`

Comment: What would you want it to do? Would you prefer .css() just do nothing? It's meant to edit CSS, not do nothing. Seems like throwing an error is the desired response.

Comment: Perhaps they're expecting it to work like `.val()`, `.text()`, etc. where they return something when no params are passed and set it otherwise... But that's a bit of a stretch for `.css()`, what with multiple properties and whatnot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not using the css function properly. Check the [jQuery css() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

As stated by Rhumborl and Scaramouche, that function is only to be used to change the css of an HTML element.

Comment: Thank you, you're right and I'm sorry to not have checked the docs :/.